# How to check if there are 5 of the same character in a row in any direction?

Tags: java, arrays, game-development

I am tyring to create a simple game of OMOK. I have a 2D array that as players populate, has the chance to have 5 of the same character in a row. It can be either diagonally, horizonatally or vertically. I want to check the surrounding elements once a player set a piece to not check the entire board every time a piece is set, but if this is not possible, checking the enire thing isn't
too bad.
The following is different ideas of how I thing something like this would work.

```
public static boolean areFiveConnected(String [][] tablero, int x, int y){
        return hasFiveInARowVertical(tablero,x,y) || northeastDiagonal(tablero,x,y) || southwestDiagonal(tablero, x, y) || hasFiveInARowHorizontal(tablero, x, y);

    }
    private static boolean hasFiveInARowVertical(String[][] array, int row, int col) {
        // Check if the current element and the next 4 elements in the row are all the same symbol.
        for (String [] line: array){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length - 4; i++) {
                System.out.println(!line[i].equals(".")+line[i]+"here");
                if (!line[i].equals(".") || line[i].equals(line[i + 1]) && line[i + 1].equals(line[i + 2]) && line[i + 2].equals(line[i + 3]) &&line[i + 3].equals(line[i + 4])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // If we reach here, there are 5 of the same symbols in a row horizontally.
        return false;
    }
    private static boolean hasFiveInARowHorizontal(String[][] array, int row, int col) {
        // Check if the current element and the next 4 elements in the column are all the same symbol.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (row + i >= array.length || !array[row + i][col].equals(array[row][col]) || array[row][col].equals(".")) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If we reach here, there are 5 of the same symbols in a row vertically.
        return true;
    }
    private static boolean northeastDiagonal(String[][] tablero, int row, int col) {
        // ascendingDiagonalCheck
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // Check northeast diagonal.
            if (row + i >= tablero.length || col + i >= tablero[row].length || !tablero[row + i][col + i].equals(tablero[row][col]) || tablero[row][col].equals(".")) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static boolean southwestDiagonal(String[][] tablero, int row, int col) {
        // ascendingDiagonalCheck
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // Check northeast diagonal.
            if (row - i < 0 || col + i >= tablero[row].length || !tablero[row - i][col + i].equals(tablero[row][col]) || tablero[row][col].equals(".")) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any of the following "strings" would result in a "true" output. "X" is for one player and "O" if for the opponent.

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
0  [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
1  [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
2  [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
3  [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
4  [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [X] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
5  [.] [O] [O] [O] [O] [O] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
6  [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
7  [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
8  [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
9  [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
10 [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
11 [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
12 [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
13 [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] 
14 [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.]
```

I have tried to read every line, which in theory works but code isn't doing that right now. I would prefere for a solution where as the players set pieces, the code can check if that piece created a string of 5 in a row pieces.

I have also tried to read the next 4 character neighboring the piece that has most recently been set but that only check for the edges and not the middle of the string that would result in a true output.